# Haskell error Not in scope: data constructor

Tags: haskell

I wrote some simple module in Haskell and then `import` it in other file. Then I'm trying to use functions with data constructors from my module — there is an error `Not in scope: data constructor: <value>`. How can I fix it?

Note: when I'm using it in interpreter after importing — all is good without errors.

My module `Test.hs`:

```
module Test (test_f) where
data Test_Data = T|U|F deriving (Show, Eq)

test_f x
    | x == T = T
    | otherwise = F
```

And my file `file.hs`:

```
import Test

some_func = test_f
```

No error if I'm writing in interpreter:

```
> :l Test
> test_f T
T
```

In interpreter I'm trying to execute `some_func T`, but there is an error. And how can I use class `Test_Data` in my file to describe annotations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You aren't exporting it from your module:

```
module Test (test_f, Test_Data(..)) where
```

The `(..)` part says "export all constructors for `TestData`".

Answer (score 11):

You have an explicit export list in your module `Test`:

```
module Test (test_f) where
```

The export list `(test_f)` states that you want to export the function `test_f` and nothing else. In particular, the datatype `Test_Data` and its constructors are hidden.

To fix this, either remove the export list like this:

```
module Test where
```

Now all things will be exported.

Or add the datatype and its constructors to the export list like this:

```
module Test (test_f, Test_Data(..)) where
```

The notation `Test_Data(..)` exports a datatype with all corresponding constructors.